# Using a front controller in a Wordpress plugin, any suggestions?

Tags: plugin-development, oop

My idea was to use a front controller in our plugin. has anyone done that already?
The responsibilities of the controller should be

- initiate router class;
- provide access to objects registry, which will
  be responsible for finding and initializing other classes (possibly
  through factories);
- initiate class responsible for binding WordPress
  actions.

I was thinking about following the standard [martin fowler example](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) but if someone has already tried it I might want to learn from him.

Answer (score 7):

Most complex plugins do that in one form or another. Unfortunately, many plugins start with a god class and don’t use a clean OOP approach. WooCommerce is a popular example.

Plugins cannot provide a real front controller, because they are loaded after WordPress has set up most of its environment. And all plugins are almost equal: If two plugins try to handle the same request, the first one wins probably. You never know which plugins might compete with yours.

For a very basic example see my plugin [T5 Public Preview](https://github.com/thefuxia/T5-Public-Preview) (from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116659/73)).

- The front controller is the class [T5_Public_Preview](https://github.com/thefuxia/T5-Public-Preview/blob/master/php/T5_Public_Preview.php) it loads the needed classes and creates the objects depending on the request (admin or front-end).
- There are three models: `T5_Post_Meta`, `T5_Public_Preview_Language` and `T5_Endpoint`.
- And two views handle the output: `T5_Publish_Box_View` and `T5_Render_Endpoint`. The latter doesn’t actually show something, but it changes WordPress to show a different output in some cases.

---

OOP is about [communication between objects and components](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2013/09/beyond-design-patterns.html). So the real problem is not the pattern, it is the **communication**. WordPress core is not OOP, everything is lumped together; the code was and is growing organically. Without a clear inner structure, WP solved the communication problem with **actions and filters (hooks)**: predefined events, allowing any plugin to change or replace output and application logic.

Your plugin has to operate within this given structure. There are some interesting communication problems to solve:

- Make it possible to change or to deactivate your plugin temporary. Avoid [anonymous objects](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57088/73) or offer a configuration object.
- But don’t provide [too many custom hooks too early](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98783/73).
- Try to control the [order of execution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116303/73) when multiple plugins act on the same hooks.
- Make sure callbacks that depend on a specific order are [chained](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80271/73).

These are the most important responsibilities for a plugin front controller. You can delegate some to subsequent controllers, but the front controller has to know how they work. In my opinion, a front controller in a WP plugin has to know too much too often. But I’m still learning. :)

Oh, and separate the main plugin file from the class declarations.

Comment: I know that it's against the community rules, posting a comment like this, but thank you for your answer.